# How to call wicket page from servlet

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

My application is mixed of wicket and jsp page . In my case i have to call wicket page from servlet with some value in request object . could someone please explain as how to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean 'call a wicket page'? Do you mean load a wicket page to the user after he performs some action on the servlet-loaded page?

What exactly is your use case for this?

I think it would be better NOT to mix jsp and wicket, but given that you did:

BookmarkablePages provide a way to directly address a wicket page as it has a bookmarkable url  (for instance, /home instead of /page?13). We use those to load a certain page with certain request parameters (ie, /student/1234/results shows the resultpage for student 1234).

Also, you could implement some kind of listener service that, based upon a certain call/payload, constructs a wicket page and returns the url for that page but that seems a bit overkill. In most cases I think bookmarkable pages a should suffice.

Have a look at http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebApplication.html#mountPage(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)

or

http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-pages/

Comment: sorry for unclear question .  well i have a wicket page (Page extends org.apache.wicket.markup.htmlWebPage) i want to know a way so that servlet can forward request to this wicket page . i have to send some data along with this request object . is it possible that i just moount this page in my wicket Application class and then call equest.getRequestDispatcher([MOUNTED WICKET PAGE STRING]).forward(request, response);

Comment: Is there a way a wicket page can be called like a servlet?  IE someone clicks a link on a browser and navigates to a page.